# PostgreSQL - Date difference between two rows in complex query

Tags: postgresql, date-difference, sql-timestamp

I've got this query:

```
SELECT apple, banana, update_at FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (apple) *
        FROM table
            WHERE apple IN ('ad', 'sa')

        ORDER BY apple, update_at DESC
) q
```

The purpose of this query is to get the rows that has `apple` "ad" or "sa", and return the most updated row (`update_at (timestamp)`). **This query works.**

My problem is that I want that instead of the `update_at` column, the query will show the difference between the timestamps (duration) of the query matched row and the row which preceded it.

Example:

```
apple---|banana---|update_at
============================
ad------|VAL------|2017-06-01 12:12:30
ad------|VAL------|2017-06-01 09:00:00
ad------|VAL------|2017-05-31 13:41:00
```

Result:

```
apple---|banana---|update_at
============================
ad------|VAL------|**03:12:30**
```

03:12:30 is the duration.

Hope that it clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use window functions for this:

```
SELECT apple, 
       banana, 
       update_at, 
       prev_update_at, 
       update_at - prev_update_at as duration
FROM (
   SELECT *, 
          row_number() over (partition by apple order by update_at desc) as rn, 
          lag(update_at) over (partition by apple order by update_at) as prev_update_at
   FROM table
   WHERE apple IN ('ad', 'sa')
) q
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: @RonZ: sorry, wrong `order by` for the `lag()` function.